# how to check difference of two objects nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new in nodejs i am using below library.. i don't understand example of this site.. i have 2 object..1 is request and scond is findbyid response..i want to check difference... but my code does not work please help me... i am using node promises and mongoose schema

> Error: functions are not supported

[Check difference library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsondiffpatch)

```
      export function update(req, res) {

        Job.findOne( {_id: req.params.id}).exec().then(function(Job){

       var diffpatcher =jsondiffpatch.create();
 var delta = diffpatcher.diff(Job, req);
console.log(delta)

        }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('error body');
        console.log(error);

        });
```

Comment: It seems like `jsondiffpatch` doesn't support objects that hold functions. How do *you* want to treat the functions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply its working :) thanks for hint